# How to completely reinstall lightdm?

Tags: greeter

I removed lightdm and all its config files in the different directories (don't ask).

How do I restore it?

elementary boots into text mode right now.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what all you deleted. The reinstall command from the command line is

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall packagename
```

lightdm package is "lightdm" loki also uses "pantheon-greeter". Try reinstalling those two.

Comment: I tried doing that, and dpkg-reconfigure, but nothing good happens.

Comment: Did you try reinstalling "light-locker" too?

Comment: I did't try light-locker, I'm getting lots of errors right now.

Comment: What kind of errors?

Answer (score 1):

I did exactly the same thing and panicked after elementray os booted into a command line, after trying a lot of solutions this worked out for me:
login as administrator by typing your username and then your password and then type the following commands:

```
sudo apt purge elementary-desktop
sudo apt install elementary-desktop
sudo reboot
```